# Unable to get bounding box for 2D element in IOS UIWebView Forge viewer

Tags: javascript, ios, autodesk-forge, forge

I have used below code to get bounding box of 2D element.

```
function find2DBounds( fragList, fragId, dbId, bc ) {
    const mesh = fragList.getVizmesh( fragId );
    const vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader( mesh.geometry );
    vbr.enumGeomsForObject( dbId, bc );
}

function get2DBounds( dbId, model ) {
    const it = model.getData().instanceTree;
    const fragList = model.getFragmentList();

    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
    let bc = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.BoundsCallback( bounds );
    const dbId2fragId = model.getData().fragments.dbId2fragId;
    const fragIds = dbId2fragId[dbId];

    if( Array.isArray( fragIds ) ) {
        for( let i = 0; i < fragIds.length; i++ ) {
            find2DBounds( fragList, fragIds[i], dbId, bc );
        }
    } else if( typeof fragIds === 'number' ) {
        find2DBounds( fragList, fragIds, dbId, bc );
    }

    return bc.bounds;
}


var model = this.viewer.model; 
 var modelData = model.getData();
 var itree = modelData.instanceTree;
itree.enumNodeChildren(itree.getRootId(), function (dbId) {   
// Here you go
cosnt bondingBox = get2DBounds( dbId, viewer.model );

}
```

This code is correctly in browser and getting correct bounding box for 2D elements.
But when I tried to execute this code in browser through IOS, I am not getting bounding box for 2D elements.

Process of use above code through IOS :
- Design a UIWebView in IOS
- Embed html page
- Embed above java script code to into html page
- Get all element ids for 2D sheet.
- Get bounding box for those using above code.

observed that bounding box are infinity for all 2D entities.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with these approach?

Comment: This might be an issue of the Forge Viewer, I'm checking with our engineering team, and will get you back A.S.A.P.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an issue of the viewer internal API. I have logged a request as `LMV-3154` in our internal case system to let our engineering team allocate time to investigate. It might take time to figure out what happened. You can send the request id to `forge.help@autodesk.com` to track updates in the future.

Apologies for any inconvenience caused.

**Update 2021**

Here is the working code snippet for viewer v7.x

```js
function find2DBounds( fragList, fragId, dbId, bc ) {
    const mesh = fragList.getVizmesh( fragId );
    const vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader( mesh.geometry );
    vbr.enumGeomsForObject( dbId, bc );
}

function get2DBounds( dbId, model, useInstancing ) {
    const it = model.getData().instanceTree;
    const fragList = model.getFragmentList();

    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
    let bc = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.BoundsCallback( bounds );
    const dbId2fragId = model.getData().fragments.dbId2fragId;
    const remappedId = model.reverseMapDbId(dbId);
    const fragIds = dbId2fragId[remappedId];

    if( Array.isArray( fragIds ) ) {
        for( let i = 0; i < fragIds.length; i++ ) {
            find2DBounds( fragList, fragIds[i], remappedId, bc );
        }
    } else if( typeof fragIds === 'number' ) {
        find2DBounds( fragList, fragIds, remappedId, bc );
    }

    return bc.bounds;
}

// Here you go
let bondingBox = get2DBounds( 5314, viewer.model );
```

**Update:**

The fix for LMV-3154 has been released since v4.2.2, here is the updated code. With this patch, you have to pass `use2dInstancing` to `VertexBufferReader` to avoid the infinite bounds issue on the iOS.

```
function find2DBounds( fragList, fragId, dbId, useInstancing, bc ) {
    const mesh = fragList.getVizmesh( fragId );
    const vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader( mesh.geometry, useInstancing );
    vbr.enumGeomsForObject( dbId, bc );
}

function get2DBounds( dbId, model, useInstancing ) {
    const it = model.getData().instanceTree;
    const fragList = model.getFragmentList();

    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
    let bc = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.BoundsCallback( bounds );
    const dbId2fragId = model.getData().fragments.dbId2fragId;
    const fragIds = dbId2fragId[dbId];

    if( Array.isArray( fragIds ) ) {
        for( let i = 0; i < fragIds.length; i++ ) {
            find2DBounds( fragList, fragIds[i], dbId, useInstancing, bc );
        }
    } else if( typeof fragIds === 'number' ) {
        find2DBounds( fragList, fragIds, dbId, useInstancing, bc );
    }

    return bc.bounds;
}

let use2dInstancing = viewer.impl.use2dInstancing;
// Here you go
let bondingBox = get2DBounds( 5314, viewer.model, use2dInstancing );
```

Comment: My 2D sheet has a floor plan (which I dropped into the sheet in Revit). "dbId2fragId" array does not contain any dbId of elements came from the floor plan. Entire range from about 80 - 3000 is missing. 

I tried uploading to OSS and translating, and also uploading to ACC. Both having same issues. Perhaps how I inserted floor plan into Sheet was wrong? Or some additional parameter required for translation?