# Autodesk Viewer How to get bounding box on a drawing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I use the place me function in the drawing interface of acc, the drawing will show a [bounding box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7napS.png), how can I get this bounding box?

I have read the code related to 2d to 3d space conversion.

```
function sheetToWorld(sheetPos, model2d, model3d) {
  let position = model3d.myData.bbox.max.clone();
  position.x=sheetPos.x;
  position.y=sheetPos.y;
  const viewport = viewportExt.findViewportAtPoint(model2d, position)
  console.log(viewport);
  if (!viewport) {
    return null;
  }
  const sheetUnitScale = model2d.getUnitScale();
  const globalOffset = model3d.getData().globalOffset;
  const matrix = viewport.get2DTo3DMatrix(sheetUnitScale);
  const worldPos = position.clone().applyMatrix4(matrix).sub(globalOffset);
  return worldPos;
}
```

but it seems to require loading two models at the same time.
Is there any way to read it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the function `find2DBounds` for viewer 7.x in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326349/7745569

```js
function find2DBounds( fragList, fragId, dbId, bc ) {
    const mesh = fragList.getVizmesh( fragId );
    const vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader( mesh.geometry );
    vbr.enumGeomsForObject( dbId, bc );
}

function get2DBounds( dbId, model, useInstancing ) {
    const it = model.getData().instanceTree;
    const fragList = model.getFragmentList();

    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
    let bc = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.BoundsCallback( bounds );
    const dbId2fragId = model.getData().fragments.dbId2fragId;
    const remappedId = model.reverseMapDbId(dbId);
    const fragIds = dbId2fragId[remappedId];

    if( Array.isArray( fragIds ) ) {
        for( let i = 0; i < fragIds.length; i++ ) {
            find2DBounds( fragList, fragIds[i], remappedId, bc );
        }
    } else if( typeof fragIds === 'number' ) {
        find2DBounds( fragList, fragIds, remappedId, bc );
    }

    return bc.bounds;
}

// Here you go
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[0];
let bondingBox = get2DBounds( 5314, model );
```